# RestKit – map single source to multiple destinations with relationship mapping

Tags: objective-c, core-data, mapping, restkit

Given the following Core Data relationships:

- `Recipe <<---> Cookbook`
- `Recipe <<---> Author`
- `Cookbook <<---> Author`

And this source JSON representing a recipe:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Recipe Name",
  "author": {
    "id": 456,
    "name": "Author Name"
  },
  "cookbook": {
    "id": 789,
    "title": "Cookbook Title"
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a RestKit mapping that will result in a recipe where the following are true:

- `recipe.cookbook IN recipe.author.cookbooks`
- `recipe.cookbook.author === recipe.author`

Here's what I have so far:

```
recipeMapping = 
  [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectStore:_store];
[recipeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
   @"id": @"id",
   @"name": @"name"
}];
recipeMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

RKEntityMapping *authorMapping = 
  [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Author" inManagedObjectStore:_store];
[authorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
  @"id": @"id",
  @"name": @"name"
}];
authorMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

RKEntityMapping *cookbookMapping = 
  [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Cookbook" inManagedObjectStore:_store];
[cookbookMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
  @"id": @"id",
  @"title": @"title"
}];
cookbookMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

[recipeMapping 
  addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"cookbook" 
                                  mapping:cookbookMapping];
[recipeMapping 
  addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"author" 
                                  mapping:authorMapping];

// Now what?
```

Upon applying this mapping, `recipe.cookbook` is a proper instance of `Cookbook`, and `recipe.author` is a proper instance of `Author`, but of course `recipe.cookbook.author` is nil and `recipe.author.cookbooks` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this while mapping as you don't have the required information.

You might be able to setup a relationship which uses a foreign key, and rather than have a special attribute for the foreign key use the relationship between the 3 objects instead. I'd say this would be a bit fragile though as it would rely on the order in which the relationships were processed during mapping.

Instead, I would look at doing this either during post-processing (i.e. in the callback after the mapping is complete or by implementing `willSave` on the managed object subclasses) or on-demand when you actually need to know the relationships. This can be done using KVC, something like:

If you execute a fetch to get all authors, you can build the cookbooks for each using:

```
author.cookbooks = [author.recipes valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.cookbooks"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm fleshing out the relationships in a post-processing step right now, but I have to believe that there's a way to do it in the mapping. What I was able to do was to map `recipe.cookbook` to `recipe.author.cookbooks` and `recipe.author` to `recipe.cookbook.author`, but my mapping didn't satisfy the identity requirements in my original question; the two cookbooks and the two authors were different entities in the managed object context.

Comment: Ok, you can have RestKit check for entities with an existing id and update instead of create new. You need to set 'identificationAttributes' on the mapping.

Comment: Didn't re-read... Are you using RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache ?

Comment: I'm using an `RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache`.